# System.Data.SQLite 1.0.92.0 - Deleting and recreating database

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

So I have this weird behavior when using system.data.sqlite in my c# code: My task is to create a new database and create it's tables via code. if the database already exists, I need to delete it. Since SQlite is a single file - I just look it up in the file system and delete it using the next simple function:

```
public static void DeleteFile(string path)
{
    File.Delete(path);
}
```

Then, I create the database and open the connection (again, pretty simple):

```
SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(fileName);
SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(String.Format(conString,dbName));
con.Open();
```

And here is the problem - now, when I try to create a table in the new created database - I get an error that the table already exists. YES - I have created it in the old, deleted file. But that file has been deleted successfully (verified by windows explorer). Does anyone know why and how this is happening?

Comment: Are you properly disconnecting from the database before deleting it? Check for errors when creating the new database as well as errors when you try to delete the current one.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - the problem was in the code... I was not referencing the correct file. Silly :(